# Google form script getEditResponseUrl() error

Tags: google-apps-script

I bound a script to my Google Form that automatically sends a confirmation email containing a link to edit the responses to the form user:

```
function setup() {
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i in triggers) {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}
ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendConfirmationEmail")
.forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
}

function sendConfirmationEmail(e) {
var subject = "subject";

var sendername = "sender";

var response = e.response;

message += "<br>If you wish to edit your response, please click on <a href=\"" + response.getEditResponseUrl() + "\">this link</a>.";
```

Every time it runs I get the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot call method "getEditResponseUrl" of undefined. (line 30, file "Code")".

However, the link works fine, so I don't really understand what is causing this error.

Could it have something to do with the fact that my form allows 'blank' answers? Or am I missing something else in my code?

Any help is much appreciated! Merry xmas to all you guys!

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You code works for me if I put it into the form script (not the spreadsheet script) and set up the trigger in the form script.  This is because e.response is a Google Forms event, see here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the code is already in the form script and I still get the error

Comment: Just to confirm, is the error occurring on form submit or when you run the script in the console?

Comment: The error occurs when submitting the form, but now I've tried running the script in the console and it gives a different error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "response" from undefined. (line 28, file "Code")" (line 28 refers to "var response = e.response")

Comment: Ok yes you can't run the script from the console because there is no event, just making sure this wasn't the cause.  Are you able to post a link to form?

Comment: I'm sorry but it is work-related and I'd rather not make it public. But I don't think there is anything special about the form, other than that some questions are allowed to be blank and I've read somewhere that that could have something to do with this type of error.